Use public CA wildcard certificate for initial ssh connection
Let's say my organization has a domain example.com and a server running a recent version of Ubuntu with the name myserver.example.com. Let's also say I'm on a Windows machine able to reach the server on port 22. I want to use putty to ssh to this server.
The first time I connect I'll see a warning message like this:

From here I can either connect once and continue to see the error in the future, accept the host key so it will be trusted in the future, or cancel, since I can't validate the identity of the server for certain.
Now let's say I also have a wildcard certificate for *.example.com  issued by a major publicly-trusted CA such as DigiCert, Comodo, GlobalSign, etc, and with myserver.example.com in the subject alternative name (SAN) list.
How could I go about installing the certificate to the server so it is used for the ssh connection signature (not user authentication — that will be separate!) and trusted by the client computer, so this warning does not display? What attributes need to be included with the certificate that might not be included out of the box?

Note that you don't "accept the certificate", because it isn't a certificate. It's just a public key, it isn't signed by anybody else, and doesn't assert an identity other that the ID of the key.

You may want to consider renaming this "How to manage SSH trusted host keys to suppress the dialog to trust a host key." Also note that if you use DNSSEC with Windows, and you are connecting to a name (not an IP Address), Windows can enforce DNSSEC resolution for specified domain names using the Name Resolution Policy Table. Using another mechanism such as that addresses some of the trust issues for the remote host, and could be an acceptable compensating control.

@jcaron "it isn't signed by anybody else, and doesn't assert an identity other that the ID of the key." This is true of any root certificate.

@JimmyJames root certificates are actually self-signed and assert their name, though of course this is not how you trust them.

@jcaron "root certificates are actually self-signed" exactly. They are not signed by 'anybody else'. Sorry for being pedantic but there's a lot of confusion around whether self-signed certificates are 'real' certificates, and I think it helps to be precise. The way we trust SSH keys and the way we trust root CAs are very similar.

It seems you desire a PKI for SSH:

How could I go about installing the certificate to the server so it is used for the initial ssh connection (not user authentication — that will be separate!) and trusted by the client computer, so this warning does not display?

The problem is that OpenSSH can't use X.509 PKI. RFC 6187 declares the way to support that, but stock OpenSSH doesn't implement it. There exist unofficial builds by Roumen Petrov that include such support, and these can actually use X.509 certificates.
Instead, OpenSSH defines its own ad-hoc form of PKI, see man ssh-keygen for details.
My most "magical" experience with this, however, was DNSSEC as a PKI and SSHFP DNS RRs to publish keys. In that case conforming clients will not ask this, exactly as you want. PuTTY doesn't support it; built-in OpenSSH client feature of Windows does though (since Windows 10 and Windows Server 2016, AFAIK). But, as @dave_thompson_085 mentioned in their comment, good luck setting it up with Windows workstation; I've never tried it, my workstations are all Linux.
In a practical sense, the most affordable and easy way is to distribute host keys and/or SSH PKI's signing key to clients using configuration management system like Ansible.

I see myself in the near future putting together a .reg file with keys for each well-known host in our environment and pushing that out, so that the appearance of the dialog box in my question can be cause for concern instead almost normal and something that might tend to be rubber-stamped.

I feel it's worth pointing out that for many years I used SSHFP records in DNSSEC-secured DNS zones and, while it worked well, I eventually found that the maintenance overhead was not worth it and it was easier simply to distribute via other means known_hosts files with the host public keys.

@cjs this is what I meant in the last sentence. SSHFP works magically perfect but still has too much burden to maintain, especially in a bushy domain "forest".

I see one indirect way of not-too-manually bootstrapping from an HTTPS cert to PuTTY:

have your webserver serve (over HTTPS) the host's SSH public key(s). The simple way is to copy either the .pub file(s) or just the blob value(s) from /etc/ssh to some appropriate place in your web data. Depending on your server and config it may be possible to have the server access the /etc/ssh file directly, but doing this without sufficient care may create vulnerabilities that allow important secret data to be leaked, and I wouldn't take the chance.

use any HTTPS tool on your client to verifiably download that .pub value(s) -- recent Windows has curl standard, practically any Windows has PowerShell Invoke-Webrequest or vbscript XMLHTTP.

run putty (at least once) with -hostkey x containing the desired publickey blob, or run plink -batch -hostkey x and a dummy command which should update the registry similarly



Note that this is what GitHub does: https://docs.github.com/en/rest/meta/meta?apiVersion=2022-11-28#get-github-meta-information

You can't. Ssh does not use TLS. The default security model is trust on first use.
What you can do is publish the key.

Bummer. I know ssh is not TLS, but certificates are used for a number of other things beyond tls and I was hoping there was some "extended key usage" attribute or similar I could configure that would let sshd use the cert and let a client validate the cert as authentic for the expected name.

OpenSSH (including the port of OpenSSH available on currently supported WIndows i.e. 10 or 11) supports SSHFP, but PuTTY suite does not. Plus SSHFP is only actually secure if DNSSEC is used, which Windows workstation does not by itself, so it depends on whether you use a recursor that does and that you communicate with untamperably, for example a physically protected LAN with no WiFi.

This is wrong. A common security model used with SSH is trust-with-first-use, but it's not terribly difficult to distribute host public keys out-of-band in a fairly secure way (certainly more secure than trust-on-first use!) and surely there are people other than me that do this.

Yes, I even link to methods for publishing the keys out of band.
